# Django How to catch ModelForm unique together errors

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm which has a unique_together constraint on certain fields. Now when I pass data to the form and call form.is_valid(), it returns False if record already exists and also if some other error occurs.

So, I want to do something in case the record already exists(unique_together validation fails) and another thing in case Form.is_vaid() returns False due to some other reasons.
How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have your ModelForm code and also traceback errors in both cases to give more accurate answer, but a workaround could be to parse form.errors, look for the corresponding type error or message error and write the corresponding code.

PS : this message should be a comment under your post but I lack few reputation points, sorry for that.